# background-image no display

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm currently busy with creating a simple site.

When I tried to create a background-image, it just wouldnt display. I've used the same mapping for just a normal image, just to check if my mapping wasn't wrong.

This is my current code:

```
<body>
<table>
<!-- multiple <trs><tds><divs></divs></tds></trs> -->
</table>
</body>
```

my css looks like this:

```
* { 
    padding:0; margin:0; 
}

html, body {
    height:100%; 
    width: 100%;
}

body{
    background: transparent url('./img/background.jpg') no-repeat 0 center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

EDIT:

I've changed it to:

```
background: transparent url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat 0 center;
```

It worked, but when i refreshed the page again, it stoped working..

Comment: `body {display: inline-block;}` ? Seriously?

Comment: @Mr.Alien I googled this problem for about 30 minutes, nearly every thread told the one having this problem to use either display: block; or display: inline-block; to fix it. I just didn't remove it, just in case.

Comment: Don't use it, `body` is a block level element by default, don't make it `inline-block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Change this code

background: transparent url('./img/background.jpg') no-repeat 0 center;

and write like this

background: transparent url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat 0 center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
background-image: transparent url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat 0 center;
```

Comment: What is this magic? It just doesn't look right to me. It's not located in a directoy earlier + I even tried this before!! But thanks it works now.. weird.

Comment: Ok.. oddly enough when i refreshed the page again, the background was gone.. the code remained the same. CSS really is mindboggeling for a programmer..

Answer (score 0):

./ needs to be changed to ../  else it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Replace `./img/background.jpg'` either by `../img/background.jpg` or `img/background.jpg`.